# What is the correct Laravel relationship to connect actors, categories and tags to videos?

Tags: laravel, relationship, polymorphic-associations

I have a Videos table where each video can be assigned multiple actors, and each actor can be in multiple videos.

I have a tags table where each video can be assigned multiple tags, each tag in multiple videos.

A categories table where each video can be assigned multiple categories, and each category can be in multiple videos.

Reading throughout the internet, I have found different tutorials stating different relationships. Is what I have correct?

My five tables created are videos, actors, categories, tags, and taggables.

```
class Tag extends Model {

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'taggables');
    }

}

class Category extends Model {

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'taggables');
    }

}

class Actor extends Model {

    public function video()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'taggables');
    }

}

class Video extends Model {

    public function tags() {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggables')
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'taggables')
    }

    public function actors() {
        return $this->morphToMany(Actor::class, 'taggables')
    }

}
```